# update sql - c# прибавить к числу в таблице +1

Tags: c#, sql-server

Опасный код:

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connection))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    string update = "update [DataBase] set [count] = [count]+ 1 where [id] = @id'";
                    using (var comm = new SqlCommand(update, con))
                    {
                        /* ------ */
                    }
                }
```

Можете мне слегка пояснить. Я понимаю работу с `SELECT` если хочу вывести что-либо даже с условием :

```
string show = $"select name from DataBase where ID = '{id}'";
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(connection))
            using (var comm = new SqlCommand())
            {
                con.Open();
                comm.Connection = con;
                comm.CommandText = show;
                using(var reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        CB.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString()); 
                    }
                }
            }
```

Я даже научился вроде как использовать `INSERT` - через хранимые процедуры в SQL server.
НО я абсолютно не имею понятия как мне просто ПРИБАВИТЬ В ТАБЛИЦЕ ТИПА `int` + 1 через C#(код выше) по ID.

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connection))
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        string update = $"update [DataBase] set [count] = [count]+ 1 where [id] = '{id(параметр метода, например)}'";
                        using (var comm = new SqlCommand(update, con))
                        {
                            /* ------ */
                        }
                    }
```

Что я имею:

```
private void update(string table_number)
        {
            using(var con = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                con.Open();
                string update = $"update DataBase set count = count + 1 where id = '{table_number}'";
                using (var comm = new SqlCommand(update, con))
                {                    
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Операция, которую вы хотите выполнить, называется инкремент. Вот ссылка на пример, как можно реализовать это в sql: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1850402/13123688 (из ссылки: `UPDATE TheTable SET RevisionId = RevisionId + 1 WHERE Id=@id`)

Comment: @Frehzy, Как выполнить эту операцию, т.е. инкремент, через запрос SQL я знаю, мне не понятен принцип как это в c# использовать

Comment: А не могли бы Вы пояснить вопрос. Вот смотрите. Давайте уберем из уравнения C#. Пусть у вас есть "SQL - консоль" (ну, что то типа Microsoft SQL Management Studio или MySQL Workbemch). И Вам надо в таблице увеличить счетчик на единицу SQL-запросом. Это не вызывает проблем? Так Вам C# просто даёт интерфейс для того, чтобы в базу передать ТОТ ЖЕ САМЫЙ sql запрос. И выполнить его там. С тем же успехом это мог быть фортран или язык ангелов.

Comment: @S.H. да вы правы! и я это непременно понимаю, но я смотрю уже вторую неделю без отдыха в монитор, и мне кажется ответ у меня под носом, но я не могу реализовать это через ЯП

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato Делаете точь-в-точь, как вы обычно делаете SQL запросы. Просто делаете `*SQLCommand*.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: @Frehzy - только после Вашего комментария я понял, в чем может быть затруднение у автора вопроса. Вообще, комментарий тянет на ответ. Может, так его и оформите?

Comment: @Frehzy, дополнил ответ, что-то типа этого?

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato Именно так. Поздно заметил ваш комментарий. Уже создал ответ. В целом, я тоже самое написал в ответе

Comment: Спасибо всем откликнувшимся... Без вас все равно я не нашел бы проблемы! А Проблема была в том, что перед тем как использовать функцию update, я отчищал textbox.text = string.empty. Т.е. ID было брать неоткуда, собственно и ошибки я не получал ><

Comment: Кто будет читать здесь имейте ввиду - не забывайте отдыхать xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример типичного SQL запроса в БД для увеличения на 1

```
var connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=usersdb;Integrated Security=True";
var sqlQuery = "UPDATE DataBase SET count += 1 WHERE id = '*someId*'";
     
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection);
    int addRowsCount = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("Обновлено строк: {0}", addRowsCount);
}
```

По-хорошему, стоит чуть подправить это в виде параметризованного запроса. Это гораздо безопаснее. Выглядеть это будет следующим образом:

```
var connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=usersdb;Integrated Security=True";
var sqlQuery = "UPDATE DataBase SET count += 1 WHERE id = @id";
     
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection);
    var id = new SqlParameter("@id", *someId*);
    command.Parameters.Add(id);
    int addRowsCount = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("Обновлено строк: {0}", addRowsCount);
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!